# How to establish one to many relationship in Dynamo DB?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 different JSON Files. One with user details and other with order details. Order details table has a column user_id to match the user ordered for. I have to create a dynamo db table that has the order details nested inside the user details and insert the values from the Json files into this table using a spring-boot app. Can someone help me with this ? Do we have any example code ?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is NOT a relational DB so you can't have relations per se.
However, you have two ways (at least those come to my mind) to achieve what you want.

1) Have two tables: `User` and `Order`, the latter with `userId` field. When you load `Order`, get your `userId` and load also a `User` by the index `id`.

2) In your `User.java` you can have field `List<Order> orders`. Then you need to create `Order.java` and annotate this class with `@DynamoDBDocument`. This enables you to have custom objects in your `@DynamoDBTable` classes. Do not also forget about getters and setters since they are required.

Comment: this is incorrect, dynamodb is “no sql” database not “non relational”  database.